# Error en Laravel Mysql 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

Alguien me ayuda por favor a resolver este error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes colocar la imagen del metodo del controlador donde estas enviandole a la vista la variable $cat?

Comment: añade el código del controlador donde esta el método que usas para enviar la info a tu vista así como una breve descripción de la tabla que usas, desde aquí te diría, declaraste la propiedad privada de $primaryKey? para indicarle a laravel que tu columna se llama distinto de id?

Comment: ¿Qué está devolviendo `$cat` realmente?  Lo puedes verificar mediante `var_dump($cat);`

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega mas información tanto de la base de datos, controlador, modelo para poderte ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que no adjuntas la parte de tu controlador que asigna valor a `$categorias`, uno sólo podría intuir que `$categorias` es una colección de algún modelo `Categoria`, si es así, pues el error te lo está diciendo, tu propiedad `idcategoria` no existe en tu tabla categorias.

Comment: Por favor mejor déjale un comentario, pues como tú mismo lo dices no tiene más información y solo estamos intuyendo

Comment: Mm pues la verdad es que así como lo plantea en su redacción, la respuesta es esa, no existe la columna `idcategoria`, no hay mucho que pensar en un error planteado así, si llega a agregar la parte del controlador, ya actualizaré mi respuesta. :)